# How to get to Docker Hub for an image from command line?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I used the following command: `docker pull balenalib/beaglebone-black:latest`

I am now trying to find the page for this image on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/).  I search `balenalib/beaglebone-black:latest` and thousands of results come up, but seemingly not the one I typed in.

I finally found it [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/balenalib/beaglebone-black) by manipulating the URL directly.

Is there a better way to do this?  Can I get to that URL by using a command from terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Docker's registry's web fronted (https://hub.docker.com), there are two primary 'views':

Users|Organizations:
e.g. https://hub.docker.com/u/balenalib

**NB** "hub.docker.com/**u**/"

Users'|Organizations' Images
e.g. https://hub.docker.com/r/balenalib/beaglebone-black

**NB** "hub.docker.com/**r**/"

In the case of Docker's registry, the `docker pull` includes an implicit|optional `docker.io/` prefix as it defaults to Docker's registry but there are other registries:

```sh
docker pull docker.io/balenalib/beaglebone-black:latest
```

So there's a form `docker pull [registry]/[user]/[image]:[tag]`

And, if you're using Linux and Chrome, you could browse to it on DockerHub using:

```sh
USER=balenalib         # for example
IMAGE=beaglebone-black # for example

google-chrome https://hub.docker.com/r/${USER}/${IMAGE}
```

**NB** I find this a confusing use of similar terms, but a *registry* (such as Docker's) includes many *repositories*. In your example, using the Docker registry, `balenalib/beaglebone-black` is one repository in it.

Comment: Thank you @DazWilkin!  This was useful to me :)